# JQuery getting the value of a dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a row which contains an input with an array name of "something[]", was able to add a button that dynamically adds another row if clicked, with the same array name "something[]", while I was testing I noticed that the script I made for the input keyup only works for the first row. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#table").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>'; 
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    });

    $('input[name="something[]"').on('keyup', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</a>
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="something[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try the event binding on the table instead. `$('#table').on('keyup', 'input[name="something[]"]', function(e){...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can't add event listeners to DOM elements created dynamically. The script to add event listeners currently runs once on document ready.

Assigning the callback to the parent table, which exists on DOM ready, will allow it to find dynamically added content after DOM load.

```
$('#table').on('keyup', 'input[name="something[]"]', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#table").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>'; 
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});

$('#table').on('keyup', 'input[name="something[]"]', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</a>
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="something[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```